# Checkbox input evaluates as checked despite checked not being set

Tags: javascript, css, html

So I'm trying to figure out why the following is evaluating as true, I always thought if the `checked` attribute was omitted, then it wouldn't evaluate as checked. I've double checked the below to make sure the state isn't changing due to some JS. Also verified on Chrome, Safari and Firefox and all evaluate this to a checkbox being checked. Any ideas why?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="shipping[same_as_billing]" id="shipping:same_as_billing" value="1" onclick="shipping.setSameAsBilling(this.checked);">
```

Comment: If not checked initially, it should be true the first time it's clicked (because it's then checked), then false, then true, etc. The *.defaultChecked* property will tell you if it was initially checked or not (i.e. if the checked attribute is set).

Comment: Trying the simplified `<input type="checkbox" onclick="console.log(this.checked)"/>` seems to yield expected results in Firefox. Clicking the first time yields `true` as reflects its newly checked state, and subsequent clicks likewise cycle between `false` and `true`. If you're expecting some other behavior, you will have to specify what your desired result is.

Comment: Thanks @RobG - I can see the `defaultChecked` property set to false, so something must be subsequently affecting the state, albeit the checked property isn't visibly being set/created when inspecting the DOM

Answer (score 1):

you can put simple onclick function as. where `this.checked` set status of `checkbox` either checked or not.

```js
function setSameAsBilling(status){
  console.log(status);
  if(status == true){
    console.log('checked')
    return true;
  }else{
    console.log('Not checked')
   return false;
 }

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="shipping[same_as_billing]" id="shipping:same_as_billing" value="1" onclick="setSameAsBilling(this.checked);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do console log for your check box like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="console.log(this.defaultChecked)"/>
```

If your checkbox is default checked, then the value of `this.checked` will set to **true** until you change it.

if you want the defaulted to be false, change it by setting:

```
this.defaultChecked = false;
```

Taken from W3SC:

> The defaultChecked property returns the default value of the checked
>   attribute.
>
> This property returns true if the checkbox is checked by default,
>   otherwise it returns false.